# How to get duplicate record as single record in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am struggling to get desired output result in xslt:

I want something Like I have 2 records in each records i have multiple child node I have to check if the child element values are duplicated in one record or not if yes i should only create 1 record with respect to duplicate record and remaining records for unique ones,

My input file looks like:

```
<Records count="2">
    <Record id="parentRecord">
      <Record id="childRecord1">
        <Record id="childRecord2">
          <Field id="childRecord2Field">Technology Asset Management</Field>
        </Record>
      </Record>
      <Record id="childRecord1">
        <Record id="childRecord2">
          <Field id="childRecord2Field1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
        </Record>
      </Record>
      <Record id="childRecord1">
        <Record id="childRecord2">
          <Field id="childRecord2Field1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
        </Record>
      </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record id="parentRecord">
        <Record id="childRecord1">
          <Record id="childRecord2">
            <Field id="childRecord2Field">Technology Asset Management</Field>
          </Record>
        </Record>
        <Record id="childRecord1">
          <Record id="childRecord2">
            <Field id="childRecord2Field1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
          </Record>
        </Record>
        <Record id="childRecord1">
            <Record id="childRecord2">
              <Field id="childRecord2Field">Technology Asset Management</Field>
            </Record>
          </Record>
      </Record>
</Records>
```

I am Expecting :

```
<Records>
    <Record id="parentRecord">
      <Record id="childRecord1">
        <Record id="childRecord2">
          <Field id="childRecord2Field">Technology Asset Management</Field>
        </Record>
      </Record>
      <Record id="childRecord1">
        <Record id="childRecord2">
          <Field id="childRecord2Field1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
        </Record>
      </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record id="parentRecord">
        <Record id="childRecord1">
          <Record id="childRecord2">
            <Field id="childRecord2Field">Technology Asset Management</Field>
          </Record>
        </Record>
        <Record id="childRecord1">
          <Record id="childRecord2">
            <Field id="childRecord2Field1">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
          </Record>
        </Record>
</Records>
```

Here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="Records">
    
    <Records>
      <xsl:for-each select="Record[id='parentRecord']">
       <xsl:variable name="MatchedChildRecord2Value" select="Record/Record/Field[id='childRecord2Field']">  //I am trying to store all the field values in paraent node
            <xsl:for-each select="Record/Record/Field[id=childRecord2']/">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=".=$MatchedChildRecord2Value">
                        //Nothing I am doing
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    <Record>
                        <Record id="childRecord1">
                        <Record id="childRecord2">
                            <Field>FieldRecordvalue</Field>
                        </Record>
                    </Record>     
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Records>
  </xsl:template>
```

Could you please help me out

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it this way with XSLT3.  I don't get the same result as what you indicated that you wanted, but I don't understand your result as there are duplicates within your result.

I've added an additional attribute `count` in order to show how many duplicates were folded into the result.

I get this result:

```xml
<Records>
   <Record id="parentRecord" count="2">
      <Record id="childRecord1" count="6">
         <Record id="childRecord2" count="6">
            <Field id="childRecord2Field" count="3">Technology Asset Management</Field>
            <Field id="childRecord2Field1" count="3">Inadequate Information Security Practices</Field>
         </Record>
      </Record>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

using this xslt3 stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Records">
    <xsl:copy >
      <xsl:call-template name="groupRecords" >
        <xsl:with-param name="currentGroup" select="Record" />
      </xsl:call-template >
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="groupRecords" >
    <xsl:param name="currentGroup" as="element()*" />
    
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$currentGroup/self::Record" group-by="@id" >
      <Record id="{current-grouping-key()}" count="{count(current-group())}" >
        <xsl:call-template name="groupRecords" >
          <xsl:with-param name="currentGroup" select="current-group()/*" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </Record>
    </xsl:for-each-group>      

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$currentGroup/self::Field" group-by="concat(@id, '##', text())" >
      <Field id="{current-group()[1]/@id}" count="{count(current-group())}">{(current-group()/text())[1]}</Field>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```